# Sorting with tiebreaks in matlab recursively

Tags: matlab, sorting

I want to define a recursive function that sorts an input vector and uses a sequence of secondary vectors to break any ties (or randomises them if it runs out of tiebreak vectors)

Given some input vector `I` and some tiebreaker matrix `T`, the pseudocode for the algorithm is as follows:

1. check if `T` is empty, if so, we reached stopping condition, therefore randomise input
2. get order of indices for sorted `I`, using matlab's standard `sort` function
3. find indices of duplicate values
4. for each duplicate value,

   - call function recursively on `T(:,1)` with rows corresponding to the indices of that duplicate value, with `T(:,2:end)`(with appropriate rows) as the new tiebreaker matrix - if empty then this call will just return random indices
   - fix the order of the sorted indices in the original sorted `I`
5. return the sorted `I` and corresponding indices

Here is what I have so far:

```
function [vals,idxs] = tiebreak_sort(input, ties)

% if the tiebreak matrix is empty, then return random
if isempty(ties)
    idxs = randperm(size(input,1));
    vals = input(idxs);
    return
end

% sort the input
[vals,idxs] = sort(input);

% check for duplicates
[~,unique_idx] = unique(vals);
dup_idx = setdiff(1:size(vals,1),unique_idx);

% iterate over each duplicate index
for i = 1:numel(dup_idx) 
    % resolve tiebreak for duplicates
    [~,d_order] = tiebreak_sort(ties(input==input(i),1),...
        ties(input==input(i),2:end));
        
    % fix the order of sorted indices (THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK)
    idxs(vals==input(i)) = ...?
end

return
```

I want to find a way to map the output of the recursive call, to the indices in `idxs`, to fix their order based on the (possibly recursive) tie breaks, but my brain is getting twisted in knots thinking about it..

Can I just use the fact that Matlabs `sort` function is stable and preserves the original order, and do it like this?

```
% find indices of duplicate values
dups = find(input==input(i));

% fix the order of sorted indices
idxs(vals==input(i)) = dups(d_order);
```

Or will that not work? is there another way of doing what I am trying to do, in general?

Just to give a concrete example, this would be a sample input:

```
I = [1 2 2 1 2 2]'

T = [4 1 ;
     3 7 ;
     3 4 ;
     2 2 ;
     1 8 ;
     5 3 ]
```

and the output would be:

```
vals = [1 1 2 2 2 2]'

idxs = [4 1 5 3 2 6]'
```

Here, there are clearly duplicates in the input, so the function is called recursively on the first column of the tiebreaker matrix, which was able to fix the `1`s but it needed a second recursive call on the `3`s of the first column to break those ties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to define a function, [`sortrows`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.sortrows.html) does that:

```
[S idxs] = sortrows([I T]);
vals = S(:,1);
```

Comment: oh! thanks.. i didn't know that existed, i tried searching, but couldnt find anything.. i guess i was using the wrong terms.. thanks again!

Comment: It is named lexicographic sort.